# Conditional insert in SqlServer Compact Edition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-ce

Is there a way to do a conditional insert in the compact edition?
I've tried two ways that I think would work on SqlServer:

```
INSERT INTO CUSTQUOTE (QTE_ID) VALUES (1) 
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM JOB WHERE JOB_NUMBER = 'EW090800345')
There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 2,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = WHERE ]

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM JOB WHERE JOB_NUMBER = 'EW090800345')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO CUSTQUOTE (QTE_ID) VALUES (1)
END
There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 1,Token in error = IF ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not :

```
INSERT INTO CUSTQUOTE (QTE_ID) 
SELECT 1
FROM JOB WHERE JOB_NUMBER = 'EW090800345'
```

or TOP 1 if JOB_NUMBER is not unique

Comment: Yes, that works, until you try to put parameters into it:

INSERT INTO CUSTQUOTE (QTE_ID) SELECT @qte_id FROM JOB WHERE JOB_NUMBER = 'EW090800345'
A parameter is not allowed in this location. Ensure that the '@' sign is in a valid location or that parameters are valid at all in this SQL statement.

Any workaround for that?

Colin

Comment: How would you only insert a row only if there isn't yet any row with such and such PK value in the table? :) Compact Edition not supporting `IF` is astonishing. I  just stumbled on that.